# How do I use /setblock and what are the possible options?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The Minecraft command [/setblock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Setblock#Operator-only_commands) is very exciting but poorly documented.

How do I use the command? For example to set a yellow stained glass at a certain location? To create a chest full of enchanted swords?

Comment: What part isn't fully documented? It's a potentially *complicated* command when you start adding data tags, but we can't fix the fact that it's complicated here...

Answer (score 4):

Here's the structure of the `/setblock` command:

```
/setblock x y z block data method [dataTag]
```

`xyz` are the coordinates of the block
`block` is the TileID of the block (includes id:0 now!)
`data` is the block data (i.e. 5:1 spruce wood)
`method` is one of three things: `keep`, `replace`, or `delete`

- `keep` spawns the block at the coordinates.
- `replace` replaces the block at the coordinates with the block ID.
- `delete` removes the block at the coordinates and then spawns the new one in

`dataTag` (optional) is tile entity data.

From [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_Block)

Comment: Please add the link of which Minecraft wiki you got it from.  And there's no need for signatures, so I've removed that from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All I really need to know is a lot about the `/setblock` command's DataTags. I just can never figure out new ones. I do know some. Here are a few DataTags that I know, for setblock, summon, and give:

**For /give player heads:**

```
/give [player] minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:[player]}
```

**For /setblock spawners:**

```
/setblock [x] [y] [z] minecraft:mob_spawner 0 [method] {EntityId:/ID used for //summon/}
```

**For /summon equipment:**

```
/summon [Zombie|Skeleton] [x] [y] [z] {Equipment:[{id:/no. ID of HAND equipped/},{id:/FEET/},{id:/LEGS/},{id:/CHEST/},{id:/HEAD/}]}
```

On the `/summon` one, on the head, I know how to put a player skull on the Zombie or Skeleton, and here is how: What goes in place of `{id:[HEAD]}` is `{id:397,Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:}` .

To make it a player, put a player's Username between the `:` and the `}` in `{SkullOwner:}` .